# Animate ng-container

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm working on a bigger app, where we are using lazy loading for modules. After we load a module, then in some cases a component get rendered to a `<ng-container><ng-container>`. The problem is, the animation which is defined on container is not getting called.

I've created a dummy stackblitz example to demonstrate what I mean: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcjkqw)

**app.component.html:**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="visible" [@myAnimation]>
    <hello [ngStyle]="{'top': '50px'}" name="not animated"></hello>
</ng-container>

<hello name="animated" [ngStyle]="{'top': '100px'}" *ngIf="visible" [@myAnimation]></hello>

<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle visibility</button>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {animate, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger("myAnimation", [
            transition(":enter", [
                style({opacity: 0 }),
                animate(
                    "800ms",
                    style({
                        opacity: 1
                    })
                ),
            ]),
            transition(":leave", [
                style({opacity: 1 }),
                animate(
                    "800ms",
                    style({
                        opacity: 0
                    })
                ),
            ]),
        ]),
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  visible = false;

  toggle() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
  }
}
```

**hello.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Comment: Wrap the hello component inside a `div` _in_ the `ng-container` and move the animation to the `div`. Would you be allowed to assembly the `ng-container` like this?

Comment: Oh, forgive me, your question is just about the reason that explains why it doesn't animate when in the `ng-container` :D

Comment: I cant, because the component which I'm lazy loading is replacing the container.

Comment: Well, ng-container isn't really an element after it's rendered on the browser, that's why you cannot animate it. But maybe you can programmatically add the animation to its first child.

Answer (score 8):

you should give `[@myAnimation]` in hello component, otherwise it will not possible to grab the animation for hello component from `ng-container`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="visible">
    <hello [ngStyle]="{'top': '50px'}" name="not animated" [@myAnimation]></hello>
</ng-container>
```

**Explanation:** 
From [Angular University](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

> ng-container directive provides us with an element that we can attach
>   a structural directive to a section of the page, without having to
>   create an extra element just for that.

We can't use it giving any attribute or adding class, it is used to attach a structural directive. it is documented in [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)

> The Angular  is a grouping element that doesn't
>   interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the
>   DOM.

Live example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-problem-solved)