# Adding animation to ng-container

Tags: angular, animation

I've a simple `sidebar` component in my `Angular` app:

```
<sidebar [visible]="isSidebarVisible$ | async">
    <ng-container #vc [@enterLeaveAnimation]></ng-container>
</sidebar>
```

Inside this component I'm displaying components dynamically by lazy loading (they are getting rendered to `<ng-container>`).

The problem I'm facing: according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57906165/4661692) it's not possible to use animation on `<ng-container>`. I can define the same animation inside every single component I wan't to lazy load, then it would work, but I don't wan't to do that. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Attach animation to parent element:

```
<sidebar [visible]="isSidebarVisible$ | async" [@enterLeaveAnimation]="yourTrigger">
    <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
</sidebar>
```

and define your `yourTrigger` which triggers after component is loaded,
then write animation as by example, appear by height:

```
trigger('enterLeaveAnimation', [
    transition('* <=> *', [
      query(':enter', [
        style({ height: 0 , overflow: 'hidden'}),
        animate( '200ms', style({ height: '*', overflow: 'unset' }))
      ],{ optional: true }),
      query(':leave', [
        style({ overflow: 'hidden'}),
        animate( '200ms', style({ height: 0 }))
      ], { optional: true }),
    ]),
  ])
```

I don't know how your lazy component looks like so you should make some tweak to `query()` statement.